# Using MVVM how can I find out if a ComboBox has changed the selected value?

Tags: wpf, events, data-binding, mvvm

I have a view that has 2 combo boxes (Call them ParentTypeCombo and ChildTypeCombo).  Both of these combo boxes have the same backing drop down list (call it WorkItemTypes).

Using MVVM how can I know when the value was changed for these combo boxes?  I have bound them to properties (Call them ParentType and ChildType).  But as I recall, my setter will not be called by WPF.

I don't want to just go off the event on the combo box because that will go in the code behind, not the View Model.

(I saw an [example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/bc8aac33-0551-4a3c-9b51-8e61fc89705e) using an ObservableCollection.  But I confess I did not understand it.  I used a value called *CollectionViewSource* that it does not explain what is or where it is obtained.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind the SelectedItem to a property in the ViewModel for both parent and child

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding ParentSelectedItem}" ... />
```

// VM

```
public WorkItemType ParentSelectedItem
{
    get { return _parentSelectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if(value != _parentSelectedItem)
        {
            //HERE you know it has changed value.
            _parentSelectedItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ParentSelectedItem");
        }
    }
  }
```

Also you can have only one collection on the view model and bind them to both combo boxes.

Comment: When WPF changes the value will it call my setter?  I did not think so.  (But I am not 100% on binding)

Comment: Yes, by default binding is two way so it will call the setter. Try it with a simple app and you will see

Answer (score 0):

Set the ComboBox IsSyncronyzedWithCurrentItem property to true, than on your vm, call this CollectionViewSource.GetDefualtView([your workitem types]), the return type is ICollectionView or something similar, and it has a current changed event.

Comment: Will that work with one collection (WorkitemTypes) backing two ComboBoxes?